# eclipse can't locate my sdk folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I've already installed android sdk and the adt plugin on eclipse helios* on windows 7. when i go to preference, however, i got a problem in locating my sdk location. my sdk location was "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools". it says "Could not find folder 'tool...roid-sdk\platform-tools\'". I also tried to update android sdk, but it says access denied.

I've been looking into some forums about this, but i only found those that has problems locating the adb.exe on their folders. Any help would be appreciated, because i badly need to develop an android app for my thesis and tech presentation. thank you very much.

*eclipse helios is not really installed, I'm using its program files that i copied. i don't know if installing it or just running the files will affect the android sdk, so..yeah.

Comment: See the more general (non-Eclipse) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369651/where-is-the-android-sdk-folder-located/47833406#47833406

Answer (score 9):

I found my SDK location in the following way (I have Windows 7 OS, and I use Eclipse):

In Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Android.
There, you can find it in a textbox, near the label "SDK Location".

I hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: It did help. Mine was in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Answer (score 4):

Judging from what's configured in my Eclipse *(and I can work with Android, launch Emulators and all, so it's configured OK)*, you should not use the following path :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

But only this one :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
```

Basically, you should indicate the path to the directory that contains the whole SDK, and not to the `platform-tools` directory.

Comment: I should point out that if you are running 64-bit windows, that will be in the (x86) directory and also if you have done a system refresh the folder no longer has write permission.  You will need to fix permissions before you can install any updates or new components.