# Where is the Android SDK folder located?

Tags: android, sdk, air

I created with Adobe Flash an .apk app through Air for Android. 
Now I would like to make it ready for the Blackberry App World with this Blackberry online packager: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/apk-compatibility-check

Where to I find the **Android SDK folder** on my Windows PC? Is it bundle with the Adobe Flash Pro installation?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can find the path in the Android SDK Manager.
On the top it lists the path, the default path in Windows is

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and on Linux

```
/home/YourName/Android/Sdk/
```

Answer (score 134):

If you're using android studio then...

1. Open the Android SDK Manager.
2. At the top of the window, just above the list of SDKs, it says "SDK Path: ".

I configured with the defaults and the path, for me, is:

> C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: there are two folders 1 is "sdk" and other is "android-sdk" which folder should I use?

Comment: @SaqibSabir Whichever one is listed in SDK manager. Are you saying that SDK manager shows more than 1 folder?

Comment: @SnOrfus No, There are two folder in "C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android" both have their own "SDK Manager.exe". Both SDK managers showing different paths for SDK.
First one (which is in "SDK" folder) saying that path is "C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" and the second one which is in "android-sdk" displaying path "C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk".

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure. If you're using Android Studio, then opening up SDK Manager from within there should show which one is being used by the system.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using windows,

```
C:\Users\{your_user}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Look for the `local.properties` file in the file browser of Android Studio. It will contain the SDK location.

Answer (score 3):

Look it up with the Android SDK MAnager.  It's not always obvious how to open up the Android SDK manager.  First of all, SDK Manager is a feature of the Android Studio; open that.  In Android Studio (as of version 2.3.3 in Windows), the SDK Manager is chosen by an icon on the big toolbar which has an incomprehensible glyph.  If you can't find it, then instead you can select Tools-->Android-->SDK Manager.  In the SDK Manager, select Appearance and Behavior-->System Settings-->Android SDK; and read the field "SDK Location".  Hopefully you can figure out what you need from there.

I came to this question after having the same problem in the Unity game engine.

Answer (score 1):

When it says that it can only have ASCII characters in your username, if you try to use letters like `Ç â ã`, it won't work. Try to change `ã` to `a` (without punctuation).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio you can find it in:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk*

If you want to access the Android SDK Manager you can find it inside VS folder:

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\**{2022}**{**Community/Proffessional /Enterprise**}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\AndroidSdkManager*

Answer (score 1):

(for lazy devz like me who are looking for copy & paste with no edit)

You can actually use `%LOCALAPPDATA%`! Just simply copy and paste the following in `explorer` or `RUN`

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk
```

Answer (score -1):

hi all i have been looking for a solution for almost 3 weeks .. finally i found the solution by my self.
1- go to search bar and wright sdk.
2- copy the file 
3- go to \android and past it there

i hope it works with as worked with me ..