# Genymotion can't find android SDK location..HOW?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, genymotion

Genymotion(personal use and free)  on my win10 can't find android SDK location,but it with a correct location of Android SDK...What should i do?Please...
Thank you！
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sI5a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GF4L.png)

Comment: Use sdk folder path not android studio path like _C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk_ this

Comment: yeah,but it can find SDK file under the AndroidSDK folder... i dont know why..ehhh

Comment: SDK is not file, it is folder, have u download android SDK@Jimmy

Comment: yeah...i mean when i selected the path of Android SDK,Genymotion always shows a line "android sdk not found at this location",but the path is correct,just can't have a correct reaction when it with a right path..check the photos under this question...hhhhh..

Comment: your path is wrong

Comment: i added 2 photos..check all of them...another one shows it can't find sdk directly  under C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio  this path..and then i checked other folder to find whether it in it...BUT........ah...i think maybe is the version of genymotion.....do you have any free version donwload link...or what...?

Comment: No need to download different version of genymotion ,plz check https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724321/5908465 this

Comment: well...i configured AS before i configured Genymotion....and even i put C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Android\sdk this path into it ,still not work...its really weird...