# Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 30.8.2 not available

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, ide

I'm using MacOS 11.5.1 and Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1.

It finds an update.

[image]

But when I try to update it shows `Error Resolving Packages`

`Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 30.8.2 not available.`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to use the Android Studio Canary build to get an updated
> emulator. [Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 28.1.9 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504508/package-android-emulator-with-revision-at-least-28-1-9-not-available)

This got our emulators started from command line

```
#update sdkmanager from canary
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update --channel=3
```

Had to accept the licenses:
[Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)

> sdkmanager --list [options] 
> [--channel=channel_id] // Channels: 0 (stable), 1 (beta), 2 (dev), or 3 (canary)

I'm sure it's only a matter of time before the fix in canary is brought to stable, until then Good luck.

**--Update--**

This seems to now be resolved with the latest update. android emulator 30.8.4

Going back to stable build.

Noticing some directory changes to the avd files, '.avd' was added to the avd file name
.android/avd/emulatorName.avd