# Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 30.8.0 not available

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to add Android R using AVD manager in my M1 mac but when I press download it says

```
Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 30.8.0 not available.
```

I've also tried downloading it from the SDK manager but it shows the following error

```
Unable to resolve dependencies for Google Play ARM 64 v8a System Image: Package "Android Emulator" with revision at least 30.8.0 not available.,
```

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

```
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.5.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Comment: It happened before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504508/package-android-emulator-with-revision-at-least-28-1-9-not-available

Comment: This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504508/package-android-emulator-with-revision-at-least-28-1-9-not-available/55510380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Canary 8 fixed this issue for now.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 2):

The latest current Android Emulator is 30.7.5.
I guess it is an issue on the sdk update site and they have to make Android emulator 30.8.0 available as it seems that newer Android images are based on that Emulator version.

Also it seems to be affecting all users.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196708236

Answer (score 0):

Use canary channel: `sdkmanager --channel=3 ...` or from ui

> Help > Check for Update (on Mac, Android Studio > Check for Updates)

And change channel to `Canary channel`.

Answer (score 0):

The new Android Emulator 30.8.4 is available to download and the issue is fixed.