# Why we need android Sdk to create android apps?

Tags: android

We are writing a code in a java file and with the use of Gradle we can compile the java files and resource files and make an APK, So here is a doubt, why we need android SDK?

Comment: To communicate with the android OS and use their features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Libraries or APIs** — Pre-defined parts of code that permit developers to perform common programming assignments on the platform.

**Tools** — Help developers to do tasks as debugging, creating, running, and testing their applications. These tools are actually delivered through an integrated development environment (IDE) that is built into the SDK. So, you can say that while most SDKs include an IDE, an IDE is not necessarily the same thing as an SDK.

Arguably the most important parts of this package are in the SDKtools. You will need these tools regardless of which version of Android you are targeting. These are what will actually create the APK – turning your Java program into an Android app that can be launched on a phone. These include a number of build tools, debugging tools, and image tools

Comment: does sdk  inside IDE or IDe inside sdk?we are downloading only Ide right?

Comment: If Tools helps to build app then what gradle does?

Comment: These days, the Android SDK also comes bundled with Android Studio, the integrated development environment where the work gets done and many of the tools are now best accessed or managed. You can download the SDK independently however if that is your preference.

Comment: Gradle is a  tool inside SDK @Berryfarm. Please upvote answer if it helped you

Comment: SDK is full of classes , but i cannot able to see in my java folder,Where is it ,I can able to use those classes ,How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

SDK, knows as **Software Development Kit**, it contains thousands of functions/methods for you (developer/programmer) to build the features you want handily.

SDK is a set of tool, can be used right out of the box, so that you can just focus on building applications instead of building the tool.

IDE, is like a code editor, helps you write code with a good interface, evolution of **commend line**.

Gradle is a tool for building the project/application.

Comment: SDK is full of classes , but i cannot able to see in my java folder,Where is it ,I can able to use those classes ,How is it possible ?

Comment: @Berry farm check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369651/where-is-the-android-sdk-folder-located

Comment: So android studio utlise all of this software in order to make android apps?

Comment: @Berry farm Yes.