# Android Studio problem - Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or currupted

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I had to reinstall Windows 11 last week and so have had to re-setup my Android Studio / Flutter environment. I have setup a few Android devices in the device manager and have downloaded system images for API 28 and newer.
I have also opened the "SDK Manager" and downloaded and installed the SDK Platforms Android 29 and newer.

I am seeing the error "Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or currupted" in Android Studio.

How do I fix this?

Results from Flutter Doctor :

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision efbf63d9c6 (7 days ago), 2023-08-15 21:05:06 -0500
    • Engine revision 1ac611c64e
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/paul/.jdks/corretto-19.0.2
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.97
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.203

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your environment variables according to your installed path and check whether the correct SDK platforms are installed or not. after that

**Update Flutter Path:** `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-android-sdk>`

Replace `<path-to-android-sdk>` with the actual path to your Android SDK.

Comment: How do I find the actual path to my Android SDK?

Comment: Search a bit or https://stackoverflow.com/q/9369651/12965265