# I can't locate the Android SDK on my computer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I installed the Android SDK on my computer a few months ago and now I've finally motivated myself to begin developing.

At the moment, I'm trying to install the plugin for Eclipse, and I need to set the location of the SDK on my computer but... I can't find it.
I know it's installed, since the SDK Manager says it is, but I don't know where!

There's no Android folder in Program Files or in C:\
Searching for Android in explorer didn't yield anything relevant.

So.. Does anybody know where I can find the SDK?
It doesn't seem to be in the default location.
Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: try searching for *adb*  or *adb.exe* maybe windows will find it better than *Android*. Or download the SDK Bundle from the link User2181330 suggested

Comment: ouh, I think I have found a solution for your problem. Take a look at this link . It is describing the location and what to include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889938/eclipse-cant-locate-my-sdk-folder I hope it will help you

Comment: just create a blank project open project from left pane ,  there you will find local.properties file , read that

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If what you say about the SDK Manager in the OP is correct, and if you have access to the SDK Manager, then it shows where the SDK is currently located.

[image]

Right below the Package and Tools menu, it shows the SDK path.

However, if you cannot access the SDK Manager, then odds are you downloaded either the ADT Bundle or the SDK Installer.

If it is the earlier, then the file that you downloaded is named: **adt-bundle-windows-x86.zip**. If it is the later, and if you remember installing it, then the default path for the installation is in your `Program Files\Android....`. The installer is named something like this: **installer_r21.1-windows.exe** (this is the current available version)

If none of the suggestions on this page, helps, then the last resort is to download the SDK all over again. On a good connection, you should be done in about 15 odd minutes.
[Download Source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Good luck with coding. ;-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369651/where-is-the-android-sdk-folder-located/47833406#47833406 for how to find the SDK Manager and how to find the SDK folder from there.