# Where is android_sdk_root? and how do I set it.?

Tags: android

I set the android_sdk_home variable so that my application could find .android when trying to run. Now I get an error stating that "android_sdk_root is undefined". 
I am running win 7 with a new installation of Android Studio, inside parallels on a macbook pro.

Thank you for your response. I checked the location and it is identified as the same location as the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment path. It still says root is undefined. I created an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT enviroment path to the same location and it is still undefined.

Answer (score 97):

This is how I did it on macOS:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile  # macOS 10.14 Mojave and older
vim ~/.zshrc         # macOS 10.15 Catalina and newer (using zsh by default)
```

And added the following environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/${USER}/.android/avd
```

Android path might be different, if so change it accordingly. At last, to refresh the terminal to apply changes:

```
source ~/.bash_profile  # macOS 10.14 Mojave and older
source ~/.zshrc         # macOS 10.15 Catalina and newer (using zsh by default)
```

Comment: If you had an SDK installed in another location before installing Android Studio, then you may have to update the path to include the above variables first to make sure the right `sdkmanager` gets called. 
`export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH`

Comment: ```export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/avd```

Comment: I was doing the same thing but was not refreshing the terminal, thanks for the advice

Comment: The both are same?
`ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Answer (score 51):

I received the same error after installing android studio and trying to run hello world.  I think you need to use the SDK Manager inside Android Studio to install some things first.

[image: android_sdk_root error]

Open up Android Studio, and click on the SDK Manager in the toolbar.

[image: SDK Manager]

Now install the SDK tools you need.

- Tools -> Android SDK Tools
- Tools -> Android SDK Platform-tools
- Tools -> Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)

For each Android release you are targeting, hit the appropriate Android X.X folder and select (at a minimum):

- SDK Platform
- A system image for the emulator, such as  ARM EABI v7a System Image

The SDK Manager will run (this can take a while) and download and install the various SDKs.

Inside Android Studio, File->Project Structure will show you where your Android sdks are installed.  As you can see mine is c:\users\Joe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1.

[image]

If I navigate to C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\sources you can see the various Android SDKs installed there...

[image: SDK Directories]

Comment: Good answer. Terrible hand-drawn arrow.

Answer (score 49):

Open the terminal and run the command:
    nano $HOME/.bashrc
aggregate the follow line:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Ctrl+o save and ctrl+x close.

And run the command:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc

echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Answer (score 21):

MAC - one liner

```
echo "export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk \
      export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk \
      export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd" \
>> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 17):

android_sdk_root is a system variable which points to root folder of android sdk tools. 
You probably get the error because the variable is not set.
To set it in Android Studio go to:

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location
3. SDK location select Android SDK location

If you have installed android SDK please refer to this answer to find the path to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702396/3625900

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the above answers, `ANDROID_HOME`, which also points to the SDK installation directory, is deprecated.
If you continue to use it, the following rules apply:

- If `ANDROID_HOME` is ***defined and contains a valid SDK installation***, its value is used instead of the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.
- If `ANDROID_HOME` ***is not defined***, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used.
- If ANDROID_HOME is ***defined but does not exist*** or does not contain a valid SDK installation, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used instead.

Answer (score 10):

You need to make a system env variable with the name: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
and it's value should be C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Sdk\tools\bin
worked for me

Comment: This should be marked as the answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

#### `ANDROID_HOME`

**Deprecated** (in Android Studio), use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` instead.

#### `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Installation directory of **Android SDK** package.

*Example: `C:\AndroidSDK` or `/usr/local/android-sdk/`*

#### `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`

Installation directory of **Android NDK** package. (WITHOUT ANY SPACE)

*Example: `C:\AndroidNDK` or `/usr/local/android-ndk/`*

#### `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`

Location of SDK related **data/user** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\` or `~/.android/`*

#### `ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME`

Location of **emulator-specific** **data** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\` or `~/.android/`*

#### `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`

Location of **AVD-specific** **data** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\avd\` or `~/.android/avd/`*

#### `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`

Installation directory of **JDK** (aka Java SDK) package.

**Note:** This is used to run Android Studio(and other Java-based applications). Actually when you run Android Studio, it checks for `JDK_HOME` then `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to use.

Answer (score 5):

on Mac edit .bash_profile use code or vim

```
code ~/.bash_profile
```

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 4):

For macOS with zshrc:

ANDROID_HOME is depreciated, use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead

1. Ensure that Android Build Tools is installed. Check if it exists in your File Directory
2. Get the path to your SDK. Usually it is `/Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk`
3. Add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT as a path to your Environment variables:
   `echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.zshenv`
4. Apply the changes with `source ~/.zshrc`
5. Check if it was saved by ...

   - ... checking the specific environment variable `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
   - ... checking the complete list of environment variables on your system `env`

You can apply this process to every environment variable beeing installed on your macOS system. It took me a while to comprehend it for myself

Comment: According to the documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar it is actually the other way round. Use `ANDROID_HOME`. The environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` is deprecated. Some tools like Android Studio and Android Gradle plugin check if they are consistent if both are present.

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Studio 3.2.1** I got this error because **I installed a new API(28) level emulator without installing that API SDK components**. After I installed SDK platform and SDK platform tools for the API level 28 and updated Android Emulator the emulator started running.

Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to change it :

Step 1 :

Open a Terminal / CMD As Administrator (Right-click on cmd and click "Run as Administrator")

Step 2:

type in " set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=E:\Android\sdk\ " (type it without the quotes and replace "E:\Android\sdk" with your actual sdk file path location - Mine was : C:\Users\YOUR_ACCOUNT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

step 3:

Press "Enter" and i noticed nothing happened

Step 4:

Build your app again  and it should reflect your file path.
For me it doisplayed as :

Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Kurt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kurt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

I got that info from this site :

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#android_sdk_root

Check it out for more information
Have Fun!!

Answer (score 0):

on mac os
you can try
brew install gradle

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://kashanhaider.com/set-up-android-environment-variables-on-macos/) tutorial to set up my [android environment variables](https://kashanhaider.com/set-up-android-environment-variables-on-macos/) I  was on mac and I had all the required environmental variable setup and working already. but i was still getting this error that requires environment ANDROID_SDK_ROOT.

I already had an android SDK exported environment variable.

So, what I simply did is adding ANDROID_HOME to the path with the following commands:
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME`

and it worked for me on macOS

Answer (score -1):

A common mistake that people tend to make when setting the root is capitalization errors in the path, or accidental spacing. Hence, I would recommend you check that. If that does not solve it, then check if the folder you are linking to still exists, or was accidentally moved into the trash.