# How to define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (Xamarin.Forms on Mac OS)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

When I run my program (which works fine on iOS), I get the following error.

```
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

I have my Android SDK at `/Users/James/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx`. I have entered that into `Android SDK Location` under Tools -> Android SDK Manager -> Locations.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this you first use Xamarin.android in visual-studio-mac?Maybe when you add android ,something is missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391511/where-is-android-sdk-root-and-how-do-i-set-it